# Regular Expression to express Date in CCYYMMDD Format

Tags: regex, date

I need the regular Expression code for displaying a given date in CCYYMMDD  Format

Comment: Could you provide an example and more info about what are you trying to do? Regular Expressions are usually used to match text, not for formating/displaying text. Maybe what you need doesn't require Regex, or maybe it does. Please, provide more info.

Comment: @user578104: I think it might be valuable to add the programming language you want to use since you probably might be looking for `strftime` or equivalent.

Comment: You can use RegEx search/replace to format a date in another format to your preferred, but to do so, we would need to see relevant examples of the input strings.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here with RegExp? If you have a Date object, or a date function in your programming language, you can make use of it, it is likely there's a print method/function.

Answer (score 1):

A plain regexp, which expresses (like the headline says) the date, might look like this without quoting:

```
"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
```

If you know it is limited to the near future, you can set the first digit to 2, maybe the second to 0, the third to 1 and so on.

```
"201[0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
```

For displaying a given date, I see no sense. Unix-date?

```
date +%Y%m%d
20110317
```

But that's not a regular expression. Hm. Well - it is, kind of. :)